# SwiftUI Multiple Pickers Unclickable

Tags: swiftui

I have multiple Pickers in an HStack-->VStack.  I want to create an hour, minute, seconds picker. 
The way I have it setup now is what I am looking for however the 2nd and 3rd picker's do not allow for user interaction.  Any ideas as to why?

[image]

```
struct TimePicker: View {

    @State private var selectedHour = 0
    @State private var selectedMin = 0
    @State private var selectedSecond = 0


    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            VStack {
                Picker(selection: self.$selectedHour, label: Text("Hour")) {
                    ForEach(0..<24) { hour in
                        Text("\(hour) Hour")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .clipped()
            .border(Color.blue)

            VStack {
                Picker(selection: self.$selectedMin, label: Text("Min")) {
                    ForEach(0..<61) { min in
                        Text("\(min) Min")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .clipped()
            .border(Color.yellow)

            VStack {
                Picker(selection: self.$selectedSecond, label: Text("Sec")) {
                    ForEach(0..<61) { sec in
                        Text("\(sec) Sec")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .clipped()
            .border(Color.purple)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copying and pasting into a new project, all three pickers behave normally. Are you using Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2 simulator?

Comment: Interesting - 11.1, let me upgrade and rebuild.  Thanks.

Comment: I actually do remember a lot of problems with Pickers on 11.1. That's probably it.

Comment: Works with a new project on 11.2, not in an existing project.  Odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickers are very buggy in Xcode 11.1 / iOS 13.1. Try upgrading and it should be resolved.